# How do I create a generic Factory which receives a Type?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create a factory method (sort of; It actually polls a remote service) which takes in a generic of type `T` which is an interface of type `IMessage` and returns a `List<IMessage>`. So the code would look something like:

```
public class Client<T> : IClient where T: Type, IMessage
{

  public Client(IExternalClient client, string url)
  {
    this.client = client;
    this.queueUrl = queueUrl;
  }

  public List<IMessage> GetNextMessage()
  {
    var message = new Message();
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), message);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run into problems when I try to create a new client:

```
var Foo = new Client<BarMessage>(new ExternalClient(), url);
```

gives me the error

> The type BarMessage cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method 'Client'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'BarMessage' to 'System.Type'

If I modify my class declaration to:

```
public class Client<T> : IClient where T: IMessage
```

Then a direct call to the constructor compiles. However, then my factory method breaks down as I am passing in the `IMessage` Type rather than an instance of `IMessage`.

```
public class ClientFactory : Dictionary<string, Func<IClient>>, IClientFactory
{
    public IClient CreateNew<T>(KeyValuePair<T, string> urlInfo) where T : IMessage
    {
        return new Client<T>(new ExternalClient(), urlInfo.Value);
    }
}
```

When I call my factory method:

```
clientFactory.CreateNew(urlInfo)
```

where urlInfo is a `KeyValuePair<Type,string>` containing a Type and a URL (the two pieces of information necessary, in addition to the External Client to create my Client) I get the compile time error

> The type 'System.Type' cannot be used as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 
>   IClientFactory.CreateNew)'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'System.Type' to 'IMessage'.

I have a feeling I'm bumping up against a covariance problem, but if so I don't know enough to diagnose it. Is what I'm trying to do possible in C# (and I just have a syntax or design problem), or am I trying to do something the language doesn't support?

Comment: if you want to pass `Type` simply use `KeyValuePair<Type, string>`. why method has to be generic?

Comment: What I understand is you want `T` in `CreateNew<T>` to implement `IMessage`. If that's right, you could just use change all generics to `IMessage`:
`public class Client<IMessage> : IClient` and `public IClient CreateNew<IMessage>(KeyValuePair<IMessage, string> urlInfo)`

Comment: let me ask in another way. What `Type` and `IMessage` have in common?

Comment: @Mat I tried that initially, but then my factory method must accept an instance of IMessage, not the Type IMessage. I don't have an IMessage to provide it, and creating an empty one just to pull the Type back out seems wrong, assuming that it works.

Comment: Unless T is derived from `List<IMessage>` that cast is not going to work.

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary Hrm. I'll try architecting it that way. I'll report back. Thanks for the possible new angle.

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, I'm aware of that. Such is the risk with reflection. I'll just have to handle those errors cleanly. I should have complete control over what kinds of Messages I'm polling for though, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Necoras what would `Type` be in `KeyValuePair<Type, string>`, in a concrete example ?

Comment: @Mat Something like an EmailMessage. The External Client in question is currently only used for Amazon SQS queues, though it could conceivably hook up to any Queuing system. Those messages would then be converted by GetNextMessage() into internal IMessages (ex: EmailMessage) for processing a Message Handler which takes a specific type of IMessage (ex: EmailMessageHandler).

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary Your suggestion does seem to work. At the very least, it compiles and doesn't break my unit tests which weren't testing the factory. I still need to write the factory tests, so there's still some verification to be done there. I'm glad to have a functional solution, but it definitely feels less elegant to pass in the parameter via a KVP rather than making the Client Generic. Thanks for the suggestion; if you write it up as an answer I'll mark it as such once I've got the requisite unit tests passing.

Comment: @Necoras That logic just won't work; you can't expect `Type` to be a subclass of `IMessage`. I still believe that changing every generics to `IMessage` is a solution, even if it's not pretty. The reason is that you could be passing Any `Type` in your `KeyValuePair`, and like I said in my first sentence, at compile time the program can't tell if it's Really an `IMessage`. Sadly, I think you'll have to redesign that factory method.

Comment: Or like M.kazem Akhgary said, remove generics altogether from it. Depends on how you want to call the method.